# how to check for robustness for categorical variables in Stata

Tags: stata, logit

I performed logit regression on my variables. I have 10 variables, all are categorical varibales. After performing logit, I want to check for robustness. How do I got about it in STATA

Comment: What do you  mean by "check for robustness"?

Answer (score 1):

In general, what econometricians refer to as a "robustness check" is a check on the change of some coefficients when we add or drop covariates. In linear regression models, this is pretty easy.

However, in a logit (or another non-linear probability model), it's actually quite hard because the coefficients change size with the total amount of variation explained in the model.

A solution for this was proposed by the sociologists Holm, Karlson & Breen in [SMx 2012](http://smx.sagepub.com/content/42/1/286), [SMR 2013](http://smr.sagepub.com/content/42/2/164). It is implemented in Stata via the **khb** command.